# Доступ к ресурсу с приоритетами

Tags: c, многопоточность

День добрый.
Есть некоторый разделяемый ресурс с операциями чтения/записи. Известно что операций чтения гораздо больше, чем записи.
Как организовать доступ к такому объекту? 
Понятно, что можно просто использовать семафор, и блочить на каждый поток ресурс, вне зависимости чтение это или запись.

Comment: К сожалению, rw-lock не доступен в стандарте, так что придётся использовать платформо-специфические штуки. Какая у вас платформа?

Comment: код пишется под Unix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Может, вам нужен [Readers–writer lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)?

Множество потоков могут читать

Только один поток может писать

**Функции pthread:**

```
pthread_rwlock_init()
pthread_rwlock_rdlock()
pthread_rwlock_wrlock()
pthread_rwlock_unlock()
```

**Winapi** - [SRW Locks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Если пишите под Unix, то можно использовать блокировку чтения-записи *pthread_rwlock*.
Она работает следующим образом :
захватить блокировку на чтение и "мониторить" ресурс без модификации данных смогут одновременно N потоков. Если же какой-либо из потоков захватывает блокировку на запись, то продолжить работу этот поток сможет тогда, когда не захвачено ни одной блокировки на чтение (читателей у ресурса в текущий момент нет). Пока поток эксклюзивно удерживает блокировку на запись, все остальные читатели и писатели ждут.
Обычно, потоки-писатели находятся в приоритете, т.е. если какой-то из потоков ждет возможности записи, доступ новых читателей к ресурсу блокируется (чтобы поток-писатель не ожидал бесконечно) и они ждут, пока отработает поток-писатель. В некоторых реализациях эту приоритетность по идее можно менять.
Если же Вы пишите под Windows, то, возможно, стоит обратить внимание на shared_mutex.